# Sharepoint Online Unable to Deploy Webpart on Tenant

Tags: spfx-webparts, app-catalog

I know this might be duplicated but I could not find the solution.

```
//package-solution.json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    "name": "a-client-side-solution",
    "id": "",
    "version": "1.0.0.8",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/a.sppkg"
  }
}
```

```
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "....." (WebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load URL 'https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/appcatalog/ClientSideAssets/1f6c0c7d-438d-40fe-b185-0a2510e877d1/webpart-factory-imagesectionwebpartstrings_en-us_536e65149b0acf4d52c0043073b9fc59.js' for resource 'ImageSectionWebPartStrings' in component '22b74b02-870a-41a1-a278-6252f8989515' (ImageSectionWebPart). There was a network problem. This may be a problem with a HTTPS certificate. Make sure you have the right certificate.

***INNERERROR:
***Failed to load URL 'https://publiccdn.sharepointonline.com/tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/appcatalog/ClientSideAssets/1f6c0c7d-438d-40fe-b185-0a2510e877d1/webpart-factory-imagesectionwebpartstrings_en-us_536e65149b0acf4d52c0043073b9fc59.js' for resource 'ImageSectionWebPartStrings' in component '22b74b02-870a-41a1-a278-6252f8989515' (ImageSectionWebPart). There was a network problem. This may be a problem with a HTTPS certificate. Make sure you have the right certificate.
***CALLSTACK:
Error
    at t [as constructor] (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2d455b42d24fafbcc61beda1baff1682.js:4:53271)
    at new t (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2d455b42d24fafbcc61beda1baff1682.js:20:64771)
    at Function.e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2d455b42d24fafbcc61beda1baff1682.js:20:107382)
    at Function.e.buildLoadComponentError (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2d455b42d24fafbcc61beda1baff1682.js:20:103413)
    at https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_en-us_2d455b42d24fafbcc61beda1baff1682.js:20:96968




//after uploading in APPs Catalog
Deployment failed.  Correlation ID: ......
Enabled Yes
Valid App Package Yes
Deployed No
Tenant Deployed No
```

1. yo @microsoft/sharepoint
2. solution name is a
3. ./config/package-solution.json modified the version number

```
#Attempted these command
gulp clean
gulp build
gulp bundle --ship
gulp package-solution --ship
```

My developing environment

- OS: Ubuntu LTS 18.04
- node 10.19.0
- gulp CLI version: 2.2.0 ,Local version: 3.9.1
- "devDependencies":

  - "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.10.0",
  - "react": "16.8.5",

Reference Materials I have read and tried

- [Deploy SPFX webparts to SP website](http://www.sharepointsamples.com/deploy-sharepoint-framework-webpart-to-sharepoint-site/)
- [SPFx failed to Load Component](https://www.koskila.net/failed-to-load-component-original-error-failed-to-load-path-dependency-contosospfxwebpartlocalization-from-component-guid-contosospfxwebpart/)
- [SharePoint Framework Deployment error: failed to load URL from CDN](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/254129/sharepoint-framework-deployment-error-failed-to-load-url-from-cdn)

Please advise the possible solution?

Comment: Do you have another tenant you could try deploying to? I know Microsoft has some problems right now, the error "There was a network problem." might indicate that this is just a temporary problem...

Comment: Yes. Its strange because My teams can deploy using windows OS and using my Account to deploy, so I eliminated the problem of permission problem.  I have tried Windows OS to do the exact same steps. Any chance my settings are incorrect ?